# Autonumber with custom setting

Tags: customsetting, auto-number

I have a custom setting to numerate the opps by year.

When an opp is insert, it fires a trigger that call to the method 'renombrarOppEmpresa'.

I look for the record of the custom setting per year, I look for its value in the field Numero__c and I use it in the name of the opportunity. Then I increase the value of the Numero__c field of the corresponding custom setting record by 1.

```
public static void renombrarOppEmpresa(List<Opportunity> listaOpps){
    system.debug('Clase OportunityMethods, renombrarIdOppEmpresa');
    Set<AutoNumberOppCorporativo__c> setAutoNumberParaModificar = new Set<AutoNumberOppCorporativo__c>();
    String num = '';
    String idOpp = '';
    //Integer year;
    String year = '';
    for(Opportunity opp: listaOpps){         
        //year = opp.CloseDate.year();
        year = String.valueOf(system.now().year());
        //system.debug('year = ' + year);
        system.debug('year = ' + year);
        num = String.valueOf((Integer)MAPAUTONUM.get(year).Numero__c);
        system.debug('num = ' + num);
        while(num.length() < 4){
            num = '0' + num;
        }
        idOpp = 'ID-' + num + '-' + year;
        system.debug('idOpp = ' + idOpp);
        system.debug('num = ' + num);
        system.debug('opp.Name = ' + opp.Name);
        system.debug('opp.Id_de_OportunidadBIS__c = ' + opp.Id_de_OportunidadBIS__c);
        system.debug('opp.Nombre_del_Evento__c = ' + opp.Nombre_del_Evento__c);
        opp.Id_de_OportunidadBIS__c = idOpp;
        opp.Nombre_del_Evento__c = opp.Name;
        opp.Name = opp.Id_de_OportunidadBIS__c + ' | ' + opp.Nombre_del_Evento__c;
        MAPAUTONUM.get(opp.Year_Oportunidad__c).Numero__c += 1;
        setAutoNumberParaModificar.add(MAPAUTONUM.get(year));       
    }
    
    if(!setAutoNumberParaModificar.isEmpty()){
        upsert new List<AutoNumberOppCorporativo__c>(setAutoNumberParaModificar) Name;
    }
}
```

At first I thought it was working fine, but I have noticed that the value is being repeated in several opportunity records.

Does it occur to you that it may be failing?

[image]

Comment: Do you reset the number to 1 every new year? If not, then you should be able to use the standard auto number data type. Use `ID-{0000}-{yyyy}` as the format.

Comment: this is likely a concurrency issue with multiple transactions executing the same trigger - you'll need to implement a Mutex on the process that controls custom setting fetch

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue.

The problema was that:
MAPAUTONUM.get(opp.Year_Oportunidad__c).Numero__c += 1;

When actually I need to do this:
MAPAUTONUM.get(year).Numero__c += 1;

Comment: Concurrency with multiple transactions would still be an issue though (as commented by @cropredy)

Comment: @HengkyIlawan how can I do that? I don't what is a mutex